# How are strings made immutable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Lets say we have an array arr = [1,2,3,4,5], we can change it by arr[1] = 100 and it becomes
[1,100,3,4,5]. But the same thing does not happen with strings. So want to know how are strings stored in the memory stack.

**Sorry if the question sounds dumb**

Answer (score 0):

How strings are stored in memory is an implementation detail of the particular JavaScript engine, but also irrelevant.

You can't mutate strings because the language specification says that strings can't be mutated so no API is provided to mutate strings.